# How to bind DbContext from Model to View

Tags: razor, binding, view, model, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and have this simple Problem (I think).
I have a DbContext

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext() : base("Share_DB") {}
    public DbSet<ItemDB> Items { get; set; }
}
```

which contains a list of items with id and Title:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class ItemDB
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to bind a list with all the itemes in the Database table to the model. However I can't figure out how to do that.

In the View (cshtml file) I guess I have define which model I have to use ( `@model XXX.Models.ItemModel` ) then Display it with something like:

```
<ul>
@foreach (XXX.Models.ItemModel.ItemDB item in @Items)
{
    <li>@item.Title</li>
}
</ul>
```

However it can't find the `@Items` property is not found. How do I write this?

Comment: I think ur model definition should be @model xxx.models.userscontext. refer your model to the class that actually holds the items

Comment: Can you include your controller actions code too? This is essentially where you will load model data from DbContext. There are various different ways to do this but the most obvious is to create a strongly typed view of IEnumerable<Item>

Comment: And your view has a property Model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way MVC works is when you return a view in your controller, whatever gets passed to View() ends up as the Model property. In other words:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Hello World");
}
```

Will pass the string "Hello World" to your View. Then at the top of your Index.cshtml file, you need to declare the model type:

```
@model string
```

And usage becomes:

```
<div>@Model</div>
```

In your case, you just need to pass your list of Items to the view, and tell it to expect the right type of model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new UsersContext()) 
    {
        var items = db.Items.ToList();

        return View(items);
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemDB>
```

and you can use it as:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@item.Title</item>
}
```

Comment: This causes and error for me, that the items has been disposed, any solution?

Comment: Are you calling ToList() on your query? That will actually load the items into memory so that you can pass it to the view.

Comment: Yes I am doing that, exactly like what you are doing, but I get an exception that the elements were disposed and cannot be accessed. but when I create the `Context` without `using`, it works.

Comment: This is the code I am using:
`using (IceBoardDbContet db = new IceBoardDbContext())
                return View(db.Loans.Where(loan => loan.Direction == DirectionEnum.In).ToList());`

Comment: You are probably accessing something in the loan object that isn't loaded, and since the DbContext has been disposed you're getting that exception. You can either disable lazy loading (google Entity Framework lazy loading), or use the .Include() method to load the extra data: `db.Loans.Include(loan => loan.User).Where(....)`

Comment: Probably you are right, when I read your first sentence, I thought immediately about lazy loading, I will try that later. because the code is not mine, I was just helping a friend of mine.. Thank you! Just to be sure, is the `Context` always disposed firstly and then my `View` is being handled?

Comment: If you wrap the DbContext in a using() statement, it'll be disposed when control passes to the View. When you don't put it in the using statement, it's not disposed, so you're able to access those lazy loaded properties. 

The best practice is to wrap it in using() and pre-fetch any data you're going to need. The View ideally shouldn't be triggering database calls.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused because of this sentence it'll be disposed when control passes to the View, what do mean with when? actually it is either after or before, (and depending on the problem it is rather before). And anyway, in your code, you didn't use any include command, so you mean you should have used it?